Will non-whipped egg whites aerate my cake batter?
I know that whipping egg whites gives a cake more air. But would stirred egg whites also give a cake some aeration?
The reason I ask is I want to make a financier recipe, it says to just stir in the egg whites but I wonder if they will make the cake rise. I thought I would whip the egg whites lightly, but it also says to leave the batter in the fridge overnight, so I am concerned that the egg whites will collapse if I have whipped them before.

When making something you've never made before, it's better to follow the recipe exactly the first time you make it. Once you know what the result is, you can adjust things as necessary.
